# Use braces in align

Tags: align, braces

```
\begin{align*} 
&\mathbb Q \times \{2\}&&\\
&\\
&U_{\alpha e} &&\alpha\in I_2 \text{ and }e<2 \\
&\\
&U_{\alpha 0 0} \\
&U_{\alpha 1 0} \cup U_{\alpha 0 1} \cup U_{\alpha 0 2}&&\alpha\in I_0\\
&U_{\alpha 1 0} \cup U_{\alpha 1 1} \cup U_{\alpha 1 2}
\end{align*}
```

produces this:

[image]

I want to have a curly right brace between the two columns at the bottom, indicating that `$\alpha\in I_0$` is for all three bottom rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could stack those three blocks...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\#}
\setstackgap{L}{1.1\baselineskip}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
&\mathbb Q \times \{2\}&&\\
&\\
&U_{\alpha e} &&\alpha\in I_2 \text{ and }e<2 \\
&\\
&\left.\!\!\Centerstack[l]{
U_{\alpha 0 0} \#
U_{\alpha 1 0} \cup U_{\alpha 0 1} \cup U_{\alpha 0 2}\#
U_{\alpha 1 0} \cup U_{\alpha 1 1} \cup U_{\alpha 1 2}
}
\right\}&&\alpha\in I_0\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, here's an answer that preserves the `align*` environment used in the OP's example. It uses an `array` environment to group the final three lines and to provide a closing curly brace.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}

\begin{align*} 
&\mathbb Q \times \{2\}\\[1ex]
&U_{\alpha e} 
    &&\text{$\alpha\in I_2$ and $e<2$} \\[1ex]
&\mkern-5mu
\left.\begin{array}{@{}l}
U_{\alpha 0 0} \\
U_{\alpha 1 0} \cup U_{\alpha 0 1} \cup U_{\alpha 0 2}\\
U_{\alpha 1 0} \cup U_{\alpha 1 1} \cup U_{\alpha 1 2}
\end{array}\right\} 
    &&\alpha\in I_0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```